# Bool doesn't return correctly

Tags: swift, if-statement, swift3, uibutton

I'm pretty much new to programming and I want to learn Swift 3.0.

I've been trying to write my own TicTacToe-Game but somehow the bool return doesn't work the way I want when I check for a winner...

The CheckWin() function looks like this:

```
func CheckWin() -> Bool {
    if button1.titleLabel?.text == button2.titleLabel?.text && button2.titleLabel?.text == button3.titleLabel?.text && button1.titleLabel?.text != nil    {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
//and so on...
```

My problem is, when I click on a Button it fills the Button with an "X" or an "O" and afterwards I call the CheckWin() function via an if-statement
but it sets the Labeltext to "Won!" after the NEXT time I click on a button. Instead of immediately checking it and setting the Labeltext to "Won!".

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == nil {
         if player % 2 == 0 {
              sender.setTitle(playerx, for: UIControlState.normal)
              player += 1  //Adds 1 to the variable player
              turn += 1    //Adds 1 to the variable turn (to check later for a draw)
         } else {
              sender.setTitle(playero, for: UIControlState.normal)
              player += 1
              turn += 1
         }
    }
    if CheckWin() {
        label.text = "Won!"
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help/tips! Thanks in advance!

(By the way, I know that it's not such a good idea to create an outlet for each Button, but at first I just want to get this thing working before I start improving) :)

Comment: Use the *debugger.* Set a breakpoint, single-step through the code, inspect the variables. At what point does the program not do what you expect?

Comment: @MartinR when it goes to the if-statement CheckWin() it checks the button.titleLabels but somehow returns false and the next time i click a button it checks it again and it returns true, but the Code says that it should set the titleLabel to "X" or "O" BEFORE, right? I'm not getting it... in my opinion the Code should be correct

Comment: Above the `if button1.titleLabel?.text` line insert three print statements like, `print(button1.titleLabel?.text)`, etc. What do they display in the console?

Comment: @Magnas it returns "nil nil nil" and the next time i click on on of these buttons it says "Optional("X") nil nil" and the next is "Optional("X") Optional("O") nil". It tells the correct output for the previous click...

Comment: Please see my expanded answer below. It might help.

Comment: I found a way how it works correctly. I've named the default title of the Buttons "Press Me" and exchanged 'nil' with 'Press Me'. Now it works how it should, I still don't know what the problem is/was tho... The field looks a bit awkward now but at least it works. Still thank you very much for your help @Magnas and Martin R. Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Independent of your actual issue: I recommend to introduce a data structure representing your game (an Array would be one possibility), which you do all computation on. The view than only shows the values of your data structure.

Comment: Also, your comment made me think that substituting "" (i.e. the empty string) for nil would probably work and keep your buttons uncluttered/awkward. nil and the empty string are two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
if player%2==0
{
    sender.setTitle(playerx, for: UIControlState.normal}
    player += 1  //Adds 1 to the variable player
    turn += 1    //Adds 1 to the variable turn (to check later for a draw)
}
```

See the `}` at the end of the first line, instead of a `)` Is that the mistake or did you just copy your code incorrectly for your question?

Also, make sure the button type is Custom, not System. Changing it to Custom will make the default Text Color become white so change that to black or whatever.

Comment: I'm sorry the } is just a mistake. In my actual code it's correct.

Comment: Yes, I thought as much, easily done. I'm sure the error comes down to the `nil` An empty string isn't nil, it is `""`, so that should be what you test an empty button against in your if statement.